# Why should houses have the same price for a given supply

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand, housing

So I'm reading Varian intermediate microeconomics and in chapter one it's about housing. Suppose we have a inner ring and a outer ring in a city where there is a university. In the inner ring supply is limited and everyone who can't afford it or whos reservation price is too low, moves to the outer ring.

Suppose we have a intersection of supply and demand. Now there the price should be set.

But why not increase the price for a subset of the houses since not everyone has the same reservation price couldn't you price housing in a way that everyone get's a house for his reservation price and no dollar less?

Comment: This is discussed in chapter one (subchapter 1.7), keep reading!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question so that we do not rob the OP from the joy of reading.

Comment: I just arrived there. reading about the discriminating monopolist. But why aren't landlords doing this anyway ? I mean they are in some way the discriminating monopolist over their own home.